# Check if file exist with current date

Tags: bash

I have an backup tool that runs every day on 2 am, 
The backup output saved under existed folder named "collector"

i'm trying to write script bash, 
That will check if folder named "repository" exist under the "collector" directory with the current/today date. (i.e in compare to the RHEL date)

in case folder exist with older date, send email using echo.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote script that checks if the "repository" directory exists, in case it doesn't ,  email will be sent with echo. 

The problem is that when the backup start , first it takes the existed "repository" folder, And moving it to arch file, 
Which means that in case the backup will not start for any reason, checking if folder exist , will not be relevant , and i need a check that folder is there and with the current host date.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, the problem is if i use mtime with -1 or -0 
Although the "repositories" will be print out with "-1"  
The output of "echo $?"  on both case return 0 .. 
My script is something like this...

    check_directory= find /opt/current/ -name 'repositories' -type d -mtime -1
    if
    $check_directory
    [ $? = 1 ];then
    echo -e "Subject: backup is getting failed" check backup log | sendmail $emailAddress
else echo backup ok
fi

Answer (score 0):

Find the number of seconds for `0:00h` of today (start of the date) wrt a reference time (`1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`), say `today`.

Then find the number of seconds the the last modified time of the desired file wrt the same reference time, say `mdate`.

The two values can be compared to find whether the file has created today or not.

```
today="$(date -d "$(date "+%D")" +%s)"  # seconds at the start of the sate
mdate="$(stat -c %Y src.sh)"  # seconds to the last modification
if [[ $mdate -ge $today ]]; then
    echo "modified today"
else
    echo "modified before today"
fi
```

Comment: I though the inline comments were self explanatory. But anyway added some description :)

Comment: Hi Anubis , Thank you for the help it solved the issue :)